# Cannot get enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple model:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum person: {old: 1, young: 2}
end
```

But when I log into my console and try to do:

```
Card.person
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `person'
```

What do I wrong? And how can i get the enum hash? Thanks

Comment: You can obtain it by using: `Card.people`. More details here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails says: In rare circumstances you might need to access the mapping directly. The mappings are exposed through a class method with the pluralized attribute name.

So for you:

```
Card.people
```